# Display some content in a Primefaces fieldset while collapsed

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need some content to be displayed inside a togglable fieldset, while its collapsed. Is it possible by now?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to fetch the content from the backend when the fieldset is toggled?

Comment: I think he is asking to show data when its collapsed but the panel is collapsed so i think the answer is no.

Comment: yes, say I'd like to show some field from the backing bean in the collapsed state and another one when the fieldset is expanded

Comment: Try with https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/components/fieldset?id=ajax-behavior-events